# Add html divs and text to titanium label

Tags: javascript, android, html, uilabel, appcelerator-titanium

I have a label with some text. But on the text I need some letter spacing. I know that for that I need to use html text in the label (this is only for android).

this is what I have:

```
    var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        html : '<div style="color:#000000; font-size: 12px ;font-family:OpenSans-Light; letter-spacing: 10px"> Testing text </div>',
        backgroundColor : "transparent"
    });
```

The problem is that the text doesn't appear. Is it some problem with the way I'm setting the html configurations? I don't understand much of html.

I'm using titanium appcelerator, JavaScript

Comment: what if you remove font-family and using `<p>` instead of `<div>`

Comment: are you appending the label anywhere?

Comment: Pete : Yes I'm appending my label in my code

Comment: Randyka Yudhistira :  I have tested to remove <div> and add <p>  but the text doesn't appear